# Unable to print in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Below is my Java code in JSP file:

```
  <%
            Dbase db = new Dbase();
            Connection conn = db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fyp", "root", "");
            ResultSet rs;
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            List<String> listDate = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Integer> listTemperature = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            String query = "select date from weatherData;";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;
            int i = 0;

            while(rs.next()){
                listDate.add(rs.getString(1));
                out.println(listDate.get(i));
                i++;
            }

        %>
```

I am trying to print out those elements inside but failed. No error. What could be wrong ?

Comment: Can you please post your exception?

Comment: @dseibert there isnt any exception

Comment: The result set has no rows?

Comment: So, nothing is printed out? If the query "select date from weatherData" returns no records then you'll never get into that while loop.  See if that is the problem.  Make sure that the weatherData table has data.